# Storing custom level system in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am wondering how I would store my custom network level in a MySQL table. I could make four columns, 'level', 'exp', 'expreq' and 'total'. Only this will take up four columns, and as I am storing name, rank and other data in the same table it will be too many columns in the end. Are there better ways? Should I make another table?

Comment: Why Too Many Columns? How many do you have currently

Comment: Your question is not really clear, it normally helps us understand a question if it has code and sample input and required outputs

Answer (score 0):

In a relational data model, and for expansion ability you have to do it in a different table. by which the master can point to the detailed table where you can have as many attributes as you can.

BUT

This has an obvious impact on the memory when it becomes large, in addition to that, this approach is usually being replaced by less-normalized version of the tables by introducing concepts like "Custom Fields"

OR

If it is me, and this table will be accessible by certain programming language, I would store them in JSON format in very simple table. and let the program do the processing overhead